# Html.EditorFor a model, not a property, in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following view:

```
<fieldset>
        <legend>CreateCardViewModel</legend>

        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SetId)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateCreated)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateCreated)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateCreated)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IsReady)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsReady)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsReady)
        </div>

        @foreach (var side in Model.Sides)
        {
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Sides[side.SideId])
        }


        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
```

This snippet:

```
@foreach (var side in Model.Sides)
            {
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Sides[side.SideId])
            }
```

Displays editable fields for all properties of the Sides model.  What is the most appropriate way to define which fields should be editable for this list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a for loop instead:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Sides.Count; i++) {
   @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Sides[i])
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  In terms of hiding certain properties of each Side in the view, what do you think the best way to go would be?  Can I specify fields in the editorFor helper?

Answer (score 0):

Scratch that - I realized I can do the following:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Sides.Count; i++)
        {
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Sides[i].Content)
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Sides[i].IsFront)
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Sides[i].Stage)
        }
```